# Negative values in curly brackets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the file needs to make it so that with the help of {} brackets, the first column is output as usual, and the second column is output with negative values (sample inside the table). There may be alternative short formulas for the desired result. Current formula: ={A2:A,B2:B}.

File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwCwu5eKZdSM9fpFcyl4dslIq-y5h_roU4sEVwaZYyE/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A,if(B2:B<>"",-B2:B,"")})

Comment: @user11222393, It appears that your comment resolved the issue. It would be even better if you could post this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 , posted. Thank you for your remarks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A,if(B2:B<>"",-B2:B,"")})
```

Result at `J2`:

[image]